# Profiling sorting algorithms against partially sorted data

Tags: algorithm, sorting

We know that several sorts, such as insertion sort, are great on arrays that are 'mostly-sorted' and not so great on random data.

Suppose we wanted to profile the performance improvement/degradation of such an algorithm relative to how 'sorted' the input data is. What would be a good way to generate an 'increasingly sorted' or 'increasingly random' array of elements? How might we measure the 'sortedness' of the input?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Number of Inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_%28discrete_mathematics%29) is a usual measure of how much sorted an array is.

A pair of elements `(pi,pj)` in permutation p is called an inversion in a permutation  if  `i<j` and `pi >pj`. For example, in the permutation  `(3,1,2,5,4)` contains the 3 inversions `(3,1)`, `(3,2)` and `(5,4)`.

A sorted array got 0 inversion and reverse sorted array got n*(n-1)/2.

Answer (score 2):

You could generate a "partially sorted" dataset by interrupting a modern [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) run on an already ordered dataset.

Also, if you only need a few essentially fixed sets of partially sorted data, then you could generate a column graph of position vs value for each and just eye-ball them. That would let you quickly see the general random-ness of a set, as well things like how much localised order there is.

Comment: It seems that interrupting the Fisher-Yates shuffle would produce an array made up of one chunk of sorted data and one chunk of random data. What if we wanted to generate a sequence with numerous short runs of sorted and random data?

Comment: Hmm. Hadn't thought of that. Different sorting algorithms have different sorting patterns; several create short runs of sorted data partway through their execution. Sedgewick's Algorithms book (for example) would help you pick one that does that. The trick would be figuring out when to stop it...

Answer (score 0):

Also look into creating a binary heap, and then using the array representation as your starting point. A binary heap implemented in an array is not *sorted*, but it is ordered. I think it would be considered "partially sorted."